# If $a_1+a_2+...+a_k=0,$ show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^k a_i \sqrt{n+i}=0$

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

If $a_1+a_2+...+a_k=0,$ show that $\lim_{n \to \infty} \sum_{i=0}^k a_i \sqrt{n+i}=0.$

My argument is a bit clumsy for such intuitively obvious proposition: $\sum_{j=0}^k T_j(n)=0$ where $T_j(n)=\sum_{i=0}^k a_i \sqrt{n+j}=0$  and $\lim_{n \to \infty} T_j(n)=\lim_{n \to \infty} T_i(n), \forall i,j$. Are there any more straightforward/alternative way to see this.

Comment: On top of the already provided answer, you can also use [summation by parts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summation_by_parts#Newton_series).

Comment: yes, I also noticed it's a duplicate, thanks to SE suggestions... Same approach as the one below, I think.

Comment: Intuitively, for huge $n$ we have $\sqrt{n+0}, \sqrt{n+1}, \ldots, \sqrt{n+k}$ all $\approx \sqrt{n}$ so 
$$\sum_{i=0}^{k} a_k  \sqrt{n+i} \approx \sum_{i=0}^{k} a_k  \sqrt{n} = \sqrt{n} \sum_{i=0}^{k} a_k = \sqrt{n} \cdot 0 = 0.$$
This could probably be made formal.

Comment: @md2perpe Yes that's what I meant in the question by saying it is intuitively obvious. Solutions here including mine appear to be too devious

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would go like this.

\begin{eqnarray}
T_n &=& \sum_{i=0}^k a_i\sqrt{n+i}=\\
&=& \sum_{i=0}^k a_i \left[\sqrt{n} +(\sqrt{n+i}-\sqrt n)\right]=\\
&=& \sqrt n \sum_{i=0}^k a_i + \sum_{i=0}^k a_i (\sqrt{n+i}-\sqrt n)=\\
&=&\sum_{i=0}^k a_i (\sqrt{n+i}-\sqrt n)=\\
&=&\sum_{i=0}^k a_i\frac{i}{\sqrt{n+i}+\sqrt n}. 
\end{eqnarray}
Then you get
\begin{eqnarray}
\lim_{n\to+\infty} T_n = \sum_{i=0}^k a_i\lim_{n\to+\infty}  \frac{i}{\sqrt{n+i}+\sqrt n} =0
\end{eqnarray}